# DNS Error from VS Code

Tags: vs-code

Just started happening today.  Cannot connect to any orgs via VS Code:

[image]

Any ideas what is going on here?  On latest CLI version and have rebooted.  Same error regardless of Comcast or Verizon internet connection.  Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an issue for me/my org. Have you checked https://trust.salesforce.com to see if your pods are experiencing an issue?

Comment: Thanks, Derek.  Nothing on trust about this....